# Как работает shared_mutex?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, mutex, c++17

Не вполне понимаю, как работает `shared_mutex` в 17-ом стандарте или в boost. Такая ситуация: несколько читателей одновременно захватывают этот мьютекс, при этом постепенно старые читатели его освобождают, а другие читатели его захватывают, т.е., например, захват этого мьютекса из нескольких циклов с разными периодами выполнения. Вопрос: как в таком случае писателю записать данные, защищаемые этим мьютексом? Получается, что этот мьютекс постоянно захвачен каким-то читателем, и писатель не получает его? Или он приоритетней и при попытке захвата он выдвигается на первые позиции в очереди на захват мьютекса? Как решается эта проблема?

Comment: А про него, кстати, так и писал не той Мейерс, не то Гантерот - что в задаче читателя/писателя это может привести к голоданию писателя. Но, насколько я помню, в принципе задача читателей/писателей решается с помощью нескольких обычных мьютексов без особых проблем...

Comment: А, вот, в "Optimized C++" Гантерота- *По моему опыту, мьютексы “читатель/писатель” ведут к голоданию потока писателя, если только чтение не выполняется достаточно редко; но в этом случае величина оптимизации чтения/записи оказывается незначительной. Как и в случае с рекурсивными мьютексами, разработчики должны иметь веские основания для использования этого более сложного мьютекса и в общем случае выбирать более простой и более предсказуемый мьютекс.*

Comment: @Harry А как решать эту проблему? Я предположил насчет высокого приоритета для писателя, возможно, есть механизм для предварительного блокирования мьютекса писателем, чтобы новые читатели не могли захватывать его до писателя, а предыдущие дорабатывают свои действия... Вероятно, есть хоть какие-то наработки по данной задаче?

Comment: Ну, я с ним, как вы понимаете, не работал... :) Если нужна реализация читателя/писателя - то она строится и на обычных мьютексах.

Comment: Предположу, что при попытке писателя захватить мьютекс выставляется флажок "писатель хочет писать" и читатели добавляться более не могут, ожидается освобождение от имеющихся и затем захватывается писателем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Получается, что этот мьютекс постоянно захвачен каким-то читателем, и писатель не получает его?

стоит почитать некоторые детали реализации. На Linux, к примеру, используется POSIX RW-Lock: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_rwlock_rdlock.html

Собственно по ссылке выше:

> The calling thread acquires the read lock if a writer does not hold the lock and there are no writers blocked on the lock.

Как понимать: если писатель попытался заблокировать мутекс, но есть активные читатели, то новые читатели заблокировать мутекс не смогут, а когда последний активный освободит мутекс, то писатель освободится и мутекс будет теперь эксклюзивно его.

Как это будет реализовано: добро пожаловать в детали реализации. Благо исходники pthreads (точнее NPTL в составе glibc) открыты. На Linux примитивы синхронизации основаны на системном вызове [futex](https://manned.org/futex.7).

Есть ещё GNU Pth - это реализация интерфейса POSIX Threads в user-space.

Ну а если будет очень много писанины... То RW-lock не годится. Читатели будут голодать. Этот примитив как раз нужен когда чтения значительно больше, чем записи.